# Passing parameters to the BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, variables, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to pass an int value from my Service to the CallReceiver class, unfortunately the CallReceiver.value always equals 0, even after set with another value. When I'm trying to pass it as a parameter to the constructor situation is exactly the same, and so with the setter methods called from service. Is there really no way to pass there any data?

Service:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("SETTINGS", 0);
    int value = settings.getInt("value1", 0); // here the correct value is present, not 0.
    CallReceiver mCallReceiver = new CallReceiver();
    CallReceiver.value = value;
```

Receiver:

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {

public int value;

public CallReceiver(int value)  {
    this.value = value;
}

public CallReceiver()   {

}


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


            Log.v("value", String.valueOf(value)); // here "value" = 0.


        }

     }
```

Comment: your `value` field in `CallReceiver` is not static, did you mean `mCallReceiver.value = value;` instead of `CallReceiver.value = value;` ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your `CallReceiver mCallReceiver=new CallReceiver();` instance is not used for receiving intents. Instead, Android creates new instance each time. And 0 is the default value for uninitialized integer variables.

To make sure this is what happens, assign some default value to your `value` field:

```
public class RReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public int value=5;
    //...
}
```

and your value will always be equal 5.

As for passing data to `BroadcastReceiver`, add it as extra to the `Intent` you are broadcasting:

```
//in your service
Intent broadcastedIntent=new Intent(this, CallReceiver.class);
broadcastedIntent.putExtra("VALUE", 100500);
sendBroadcast(broadcastedIntent);
```

And then, in your `CallReceiver`:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int value=intent.getIntExtra("VALUE", 0);
}
```

Comment: `CallReceiver` isn't even the class in question here. The value he wants to alter is in `RReceiver`

Comment: So, there is no way to send there any values?

Comment: @soulreaver You should put this value as an extra to the `Intent` you are broadcasting from your service.

Comment: @deville My CallReceiver is not an Activity, I can't pass the intent to it.

Comment: @somewhere in your service you call `sendBroadcast(Intent)`. That is the intent I am talking about.

Comment: Your answer is not exactly what I finally used (I used static fields to pass data to Receiver), but your sentence helps me a lot: " instance is not used for receiving intents. Instead, Android creates new instance each time." thanks.